# [Unix]How do I know this particular mysql process belong to what process on `show processlist`

Tags: mysql, process, top

As stated on question's title, I ran into situations and I need to check something. Here's the condition. When I do top, I see mysql process with ID, say 1234. But, when I execute show processlist from mysql, I don't see process ID 1234.
My question is, can I connect those ID from top with ID from mysql. If so, how do I do that?

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't map a MySQL process ID to a system process (actually, thread) ID.

Comment: I see, thank you. But, another question. I there a way to know this process ID belong to which thread id?

Comment: Uhm... no.  I just said that.